# Kafka producer in another Process doesn't seem to work in python

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-kafka, multiprocessing, microservices

I'm running a microservice in python which implements several handlers for each kind of message.

```
class MsFeatureLandmark(BaseMicroservice):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config = safe_load(open(sys.argv[1]))
        client = MongoClient(self.config.get('mongo').get('connection_url'))
        database = client[self.config.get('mongo').get('mongo_db')]
        self.dict = {
            MessageType.create_model.name: ComputeLocDescHandler(self.config),
            MessageType.detect_all.name: ExtractFeatureHandler(self.config, database),
            MessageType.detect_landmark.name: ExtractFeatureHandler(self.config, database)

        }
        super().__init__(self.dict, self.config.get('kafka'))

    def on_message_received(self, generic_message):
        # self.dict.get(generic_message.metadata_type).handle(generic_message.message)
        p = Process(target=self.dict.get(generic_message.metadata_type).handle, args=(generic_message.message,))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()


MsFeatureLandmark().run()
```

On each message that I receive, I launch the corresponding .handle() method.

At the end of the computation ( which involves tensorflow ) I use methods inherited from the super class to send a message using kafka

```
def write_message(self, message):
    if(self.is_prod_init):
        output_topic = self.config.get('kafka').get('output_topic')
        cl.logging.info("Sending on " + output_topic + " message: " + str(message))
        self.producer.send(output_topic, message)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Producer is not initialized.')

def init_producer(self):
    self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=self.config.get('kafka').get('bootstrap_servers'),
                                  value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf-8'))
    self.is_prod_init = True
    self.producer.flush()
```

When I run all of this code in a synchorized way ( without using Process(target=self. etc. ) everything works correctly, but the producer goes in timeout since it takes too long to process data.

If I run it using the Process, I get no error messages, but the producer doesn't seem to produce any message for whatever reason.

What am I missing?

EDIT: For some reason, the last time I run this microservice an Exception occurred and the consumer ( which is run in another process) read the message successfully. This made me wonder: if I raise an exception, will the message be sent? Yes.

```
    self.write_message(message)
    raise Exception('spakkiggnustel')
```

adding this last line "solved" the problem. Why? I'm more confused than I was before